# Anatomy of G-WAN URI servlets

Tags: servlets, uri, restful-url, g-wan

`gwan/csp/strangesubfolder/inc.c` can be visited via `http://domainName.com/strangesubfolder/?inc`

I feel this `servlet` mapping strange but that suits my need. I can't find the mapping description in the gwan user's manual.

Please correct me if I am wrong and confirm if it is the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is a standard feature.

The '?' tells G-WAN that it is a servlet. If there's no '?' it will look for the file in WWW folder.

Update:

Now I understand your confusion.

Since version release 3.3.27 this has been changed so users can easily make restful URL's

[G-WAN timeline](http://gwan.ch/en_timeline.html)

Read the update for March 27 2012.

Now you need to place the '?' before the actual servlet name. By doing this G-WAN can efficiently rewrite '/' to '&' so you can use restful URL's like these without writing any code.

```
//Old way
http://domain/?user/profile&user1
http://domain/?blog/archive&2012&march

//New way (more restful no '&')
http://domain/user/?profile/user1
http://domain/blog/?archive/2012/march
```

Comment: What I feel strange is not the "?", but is the "strangesubfolder". As my understanding, inc.c should be visited via http: //domainName.com/**?strangesubfolder/inc**. But now, it is ...**/strangesubfolder/?inc**

Comment: Originally, strangesubfolder is under csp. But now, see the url, the csp is under strangesubfolder.

Comment: As i know, ".../?strangesubfolder/inc" has different meaning, i.e. to run a C-script named strangesubfolder.c with the input parameter inc(= &inc) for GET method.

Comment: If it is a standard feature, i can put many levels of subfolders under /csp, then visit these pages via http: //donaminName.com/sub1/sub2/.../subN/?cscript/para1=1/para2=2/.../paramN=N

Comment: I updated my answer. Yes using ".../?strangesubfolder/inc" will make "inc" a url parameter.

Comment: thanks for the hyperlink to the gwan timeline, release 3.3.27. i got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as Richard rightly (and promptly, thanks Richard!) explained it, this is the expected behavior.

The directory `/gwan/.../csp/script.c` is used to store servlets that must be run while `/gwan/.../www/script.c` is used to store files intended to be served as an HTTP resource.

The corresponding URLs are `GET /?script.c` and `GET /script.c`.

Any sub-directory used in the `/csp` or `/www` folders is reflected accordingly in the HTTP request: `GET /folder/?script.c` for dynamic contents and `GET /folder/script.c` for static contents.

The choice of moving the `'?'` query character (which can be replaced by other characters) from the old `GET /csp?/folder/script.c` form to the new `GET /folder/?script.c` form was motivated by the need to:

- distinguish `servlet` names from `folder` names (requests can lack the servlet extension for the defined 'default' programming language, which is C if nothing is defined)
- allow any number of `sub-directories` in HTTP requests
- allow any number of `query arguments` in HTTP queries
- distinguish between `folders` and `query arguments` in HTTP requests
- make it possible to have `RESTFUL` requests in all the above cases.

It took us a while to find the proper mix of features with the minimal verbosity but experience has shown that this works well.

Here is an example of a RESTFUL query having both a sub-folder and query arguments:

`GET /folder/?script/arg1/value1/arg2/value2/arg3/value3`

By default, this is a C script, unless another language (among the 15 available for scripting) has been defined as the 'default' language.

Note that the 50+ script examples provided in the download archive illustrate this scheme which is also presented on the [developers](http://gwan.com/developers) page.