# How to remove the "?" character from g-wan URIs

Tags: http, g-wan

I have checked cache.c <- totally clueless what it is doing or how to have pretty permalinks to servlet calls.

Update: OK, I know what the above does, but the problem is you have to call the above script first before you can access it as permalink. Is there any way I can access permalinks without using "?" at all (in the first place)?

I have also checked on this link: [Anatomy of G-WAN URI servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396510/anatomy-of-g-wan-uri-servlets)

I would like to have http://example.com:8080/servlet/arg1/arg2, without "?", and would like the above link to reference "servlet" to `servlet.c`.

Basically, like this pretty URL for this question

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27084626/how-to-remove-in-g-wan-url-completely
```

See...no "?" within the URL.

Is this possible?

I have also checked

```
u8 *query_char = (u8*)get_env(argv, QUERY_CHAR);
*query_char = '!'; // use "/!hello.c" instead of "/?hello.c"
```

I know I can't do

```
*query_char = '';
```

Comment: If replacing the query character by another character is not enough then use a hanlder to rewrite the URI: http://gwan.ch/developers#handler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can re-write url with handler there is a simple [rewrite example](https://github.com/fatihky/gwan-retwis/blob/master/0.0.0.0_8081/%230.0.0.0/handlers/main.c#L61)